# Connect to localhost giving error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This may be a duplicate question, but unfortunately I found solution no where.

**Note**

> *I'd problem a week ago about my phpmyadmin and I change its port to 3306*

```
I also had changed apache port to 30, as It was not connecting on port 80, port 80 was occupied by MICROSOFT HTTPAPI 2.0
```

Now I'm trying to connect to localhost but it giving the following error

> Failed to connect to MySQL: (2002) No connection could be made because
>   the target machine actively refused it. ..............

I tried different `connection strings` That are:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "","test",30);
```

and

```
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:30","root","") or die(mysql_error());
```

but nothing works for me.

Comment: dont have a negative man!

Comment: possible duplicate of [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refuses it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547134/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refuses-it)

Comment: Please look at the way your question appears, and read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: -1 to samitha as this question is not even identical to that question and you'd marked as possible duplicate

Comment: There are two different ports involved here the HTTP server port and the MySQL server port. Did you change the MySQL port from 3306? You can check this with netstat -aon. Get the pid of mysqld from task manager. Use that port in mysql_connect().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the only solution was to reinstall the OS, as Some Services Like HTTP WEB2.0 API was occupying port 80, so I reinstall the OS and next time installed MS SQL Server and Visual Studio 2013 very carefully with minimal number of options